# How can I create a directory structure, similar to Windows Explore in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a directory structure, with folders,similar to Windows Explorer, with R. Someone can help me with this ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean something like `choose.dir()` ?

Comment: (-1) Please be more clear on what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this for visualizing things within R, rather than directories on your disk (in which case you can use `choose.dir` or similar tools as suggested), then look at the `TkListView` function in the `TeachingDemos` package to see if that is the functionality that you want.  If the `TkListView` function itself does not do what you want, but gives the correct display, then you can look at the code for the function (it is only R code, other than the Tk calls) and see if you can modify it to do what you want.

Comment: Thank You Greg, the TkListView function is what I want.